# Float diffusion algorithm explodes values after a certain amount of time

Tags: java, processing

I have agents traveling a grid and adding to their position in the grid and every frame I'd like to disperse each pixel's value across a radius from the position, including itself, however whenever I use it the values skyrocket, any explanation?

```
void diffuse() {
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
      for (int k = -blurRad; k <=blurRad; k++) {
        if (i + k > width - 1 || i + k < 0)
          continue;
        for (int l = -blurRad; l<= blurRad; l++) {
          if (j + l > height - 1 || j + l < 0)
            continue;
          temp[i + k][j + l] += (1 / blurRad * blurRad) * grid[i][j];
          temp[i][j] = (1 / blurRad * blurRad) * grid[i][j];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `the values skyrocket` what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I have a maximum value of 10,000 set and each agent only deposits 5 into each position it's in, however, whenever I use the diffusion it reaches the max values in the entire array in about a second

Answer (score 2):

I may be completly wrong, but I don't have reputation enough to just leave a comment :( so here is my answer:

I think what you are trying to do here

```
(1 / blurRad * blurRad) * grid[i][j]
```

Is to divide `grid[i][j]` by `blurRad` squared and not to multiply it by one (`1/blurRad` cancels with `* blurRad`). It is solved by puting some brackets. Moreover, remember to add `(float)`or double to the denominator. If not, you will get your division truncated if blurRad is an int.

```
(1 / (float)(blurRad * blurRad)) * grid[i][j]
```

I haven't paid much atention to the rest of the code, so I may haven't still solved your doubt.